# missing Login Items for managed account

Tags: login-items

MacBook Air running 10..8.1.

I have a script that I'd like to add to the Login Items for a managed account.  When logged in as the Administrator, the Login Items button is present.  When I select the managed account, the Login Items is missing.

Parental Controls are enabled for the managed account.

How can I access the Login Items for a managed account?

Answer (score 2):

A managed account (despite being named *managed*) can only have Login Items set when logged in. It cannot be managed from a separate Admin account. 
I had to promote the account to Admin, log in as that account and add the items to the Login Items, then demote the account back to manage.